# Converting string to char array?

Tags: c#, string, chars

Can anybody explain me why this is happening?

```
class Program
{
    static char[] ch = new char[2];
    static string name = "Ivankata";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        inputChar();
    }

    static void inputChar()
    {
        ch = name.ToCharArray();
        Console.WriteLine(ch);
    }
}
```

My char array named ch accepts only 2 chars however when I convert my string "Ivankata" to char array it works somehow? Shouldn't it cut the remaining "ankata" and show only "iv"? Can anybody explain what's going on here?

Comment: `ch = name.ToCharArray();` this line will change the previous allocated array, and make it of 8 length. You changed the whole reference.

Comment: You're not assigning values to the existing array.  You are replacing it with a new one.

Comment: @Mahmoud This does not change the existing array.  It replaces it.  What's changed is what the `ch` variable references.

Comment: Who said it will change the existing array? `will change the previous allocated array` `You changed the whole reference`???

Comment: @Mahmoud I agree with juharrs view that your wording implies a change to the original array, but please don't start fighting over a low-quality question like that. It's not worth it.

Comment: I took "previous allocated array" to be the same as "existing".

Comment: OK, maybe the first part was confusing, pardon my bad English. But I think the second part clearly means, changing the whole array? `You changed the whole reference`

Comment: Yes that part is correct.

Comment: Imagine `ch` is a box of chocolates with only 2 caramel creams inside it. When you say `ch = name.ToCharArray()` you're replacing the box with a completely new one, one with all sorts of lovely new and wonderful chocolates inside, perhaps even those purple ones that everyone likes.

Comment: *"A character array is like a box of chocolates. You never know what you're gonna get."* - Forrest Gump

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour] - your 6 questions have 8 answers, but none are accepted.  Clicking the checkmark on answers you get and (later) upvoting helps other users find good posts/answers.

Answer (score 7):

`string.ToCharArray()` creates a new char array iternally and you store the reference to new array in `ch`. The old array with a length of two is not referenced anymore and will be collected by the Garbage Collector soon.

Comment: I can only assume you got a down vote for answering what some consider to be a "bad" question which some believe shouldn't be done and thus decide to punish the answer.

Comment: It's the idea that answering a "bad" question encourages such questions, as though it would actually make any difference to either the questioner or the answerer.

Comment: What? What? Could you explain please? When does the garbage collector collects it and why it does? my char[] reference points to char array?

Comment: Every array in .NET is a reference type, even if it holds a value type (If you didn't read about reference and value types yet, I suggest it). If you allocate memory with `new`, it will store a reference to this memory in the variable. If the variable goes out of scope, the reference count will decrease, and if it is 0, the garbage collector knows that you cannot access the Memory anymore and will free it soon.

Comment: Oh yea yea I realized what I did. I made my reference char[] point to another array of chars (the string in my case)

Answer (score 3):

> Shouldn't it cut the remaining "ankata" and show only "iv"?

No, It doesn't work like that. You can assign items to array in a simple loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ch.Length; i++)
{
    ch[i] = name[i];
}
Console.WriteLine(ch);
```